# Custom scroll bar! After Ajax Completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a small problem. I have a js ajax call to php.

PHP:

```
echo '<div class="center-right-inside"></div>';
```

Before ajax I create divs

```
$('.main').fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="right-left"><div class="left-c"></div><div class="center-c"></div><div class="right-c"></div></div>');
```

In my JS I use plugin http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
And after in created div I load another div on witch I want to use plugin... But no luck

```
complete :function(){
    $('.center-c').fadeIn();
    $('.center-right-inside').mCustomScrollbar("update");
}
```

I tried:

`$(".center-right-inside").mCustomScrollbar();`

this on DOM ready and it is working fine but when ajax is complete no...

Before posting this question I read Docs of the plugin and search at google and SO but couldnt find any similar if any suggestion thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".center-right-inside").mCustomScrollbar({
    advanced:{
        updateOnContentResize: true
    }
});
```

This should help!

Answer (score 1):

After having a data from ajax, if you will change the HTML attribute of the , you must change the particular area only.

```
> $("#content_1 .mCSB_container").html(data); //load new content inside
> .mCSB_container
> $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar("update"); //update scrollbar according to newly loaded content
```

Answer (score 0):

A very common mistake is that the user forgot to include the Jquery libary in their  file, did you forgot ? - That might be the  issue.

Else Try:

```
$(".center-right-inside").load(function(){
  $(".center-right-inside").mCustomScrollbar("update");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and i hope this can help you.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $(".center-right-inside").mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

Because you want create CustomScrollbar after ajaxcomplete so you need usage `ajaxComplete`

Sorry my english not good :(